# How to set a dateTimePicker value to DateTime.MaxValue

Tags: c#

This generates an error at runtime:

```
dateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.MaxValue;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't.

The maximum date supported by DateTimePicker is [`DateTimePicker.MaximumDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.maximumdatetime.aspx), which is 12/31/9998; `DateTime.MaxValue` is 12/31/9999 23:59:59, which is one year and one day later.

Can you use that `DateTimePicker.MaximumDateTime` instead of `DateTime.MaxValue`?

Comment: Sure I can now that I know :)

Comment: Any idea why these are different? I couldn't find any explanation of it on Google.

Comment: I don't know; I took a quick look through the source and found no obvious reason.

Comment: Perhaps it is because one might want to some "math" with DateTime and possibly end up with something out of range of the 2 inputs.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [DateTimePicker.MaximumDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.maximumdatetime%28VS.80%29.aspx) property. The maximum value allowable for the datetime picker is 31/12/9998, as represented by DateTimePicker.MaximumDateTime. Whereas the value of [DateTime.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.maxvalue.aspx) is 31/12/9999.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, but it is quite dirty (use it at your own risk). Basically, it overwrites the MaxValue defined in the DateTimePicker with the MaxValue from the DateTime object.

Paste this code into the Main (or any method run during startup):

```
var dtpType = typeof(DateTimePicker);
var field = dtpType.GetField("MaxDateTime", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
if (field != null)
{
    field.SetValue(new DateTimePicker(), DateTime.MaxValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is helpful:

> The value of this constant is
>   equivalent to 23:59:59.9999999,
>   December 31, 9999, exactly one
>   100-nanosecond tick before 00:00:00,
>   January 1, 10000.
>
> Some calendars, such as the
>   UmAlQuraCalendar, support an upper
>   date range that is earlier than
>   MaxValue. In these cases, trying to
>   access MaxValue in variable
>   assignments or formatting and parsing
>   operations can throw an
>   ArgumentOutOfRangeException. Rather
>   than retrieving the value of
>   DateTime..::.MaxValue, you can
>   retrieve the value of the specified
>   culture's latest valid date value from
>   the
>   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.Calendar.MaxSupportedDateTime
>   property.

blatantly copied from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.maxvalue.aspx)