# Why the WinForms DateTimePicker's supports maximum of 12/31/9998 23:59:59, instead of 12/31/9999 23:59:59

Tags: winforms, datetimepicker

Does anyone knows why the control does not support higher values like 12/31/9999? I am looking for the particular reason for this.

Comment: because thats the max value that yyyy can hold? i would've thought that was obvious

Comment: @RachelGallen I'm not sure I follow your comment. `DateTime.MaxValue` is "12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM" after all. Its not really an answer to this question, but a related question is similar: http://www.stackoverflow.com/q/1620858

Comment: yes because after 9999 is 10000 and that would be yyyyy (5 ys) and datetime format is not set up to deal with that yet

Comment: I am not asking what is after, but why you can't use 9999.

Comment: @RachelGallen The question is why the DateTimePicker has a max year of 9998, not 9999.

Comment: There's a blog post suggesting that you can change the max value using reflection, but the author states he's unsure the reasoning why there is a limitation and what side-effects may result in such a hack: http://johannblais.blogspot.com/2011/08/datetimepicker-and-datetimemaxvalue.html

Comment: I have read quite a bit and there are ways to hack the system. I am more interested in the reasoning why this is not supported. There should be a reason but I couldn't find any reasonable explanation.

Comment: I thought it might be an underlying WINAPI limitation, since the values #1/1/1753# and #12/31/9998# are hardcoded in the DateTimePicker source. The DateTimePicker does reference a SYSTEMTIME structure behind the scenes, but that structure supports years from 1601 to 30827, so that doesn't appear to be the reason.

Answer (score 5):

From the DateTimePicker.cs source code file, as visible at the [ReferenceSource site](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/ndp/fx/src/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DateTimePicker.cs#ba0fcd18a90a3a79):

```
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public static readonly DateTime MaxDateTime = new DateTime(9998, 12, 31);

    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public static readonly DateTime MinDateTime = new DateTime(1753, 1, 1);
```

These limits are checked in the Value property setter before it pinvokes the native control to set the date.

Not 100% sure where these limits came from.  They do follow the common pattern, a programmer taking a shortcut to avoid dealing with an awkward problem.  Some common examples:

- COM dates can't go lower than 1900.  That was a shortcut taken by a Lotus programmer, working on the once dominant spreadsheet program called "123".  He didn't deal with the year 1900 not being a leap year.  Microsoft had to copy the bug in Excel to keep it compatible with Lotus spreadsheets.
- The year 1753, as used in DateTimePicker.MinDateTime was a shortcut taken by a Sybase programmer, the company that started SQL Server.  That's the year that England switched from the Julian to the Gregorian calender.  Which caused 15 days to get lost, the amount by which Julian dates drifted by not properly handling leap years.  Not having to deal with invalid dates was obviously desirable.  Putting that limit into DTP avoids data-binding problems.
- DateTime.MinDate being the year 0 is a shortcut for not having to deal with negative DateTime.Tick values.
- DateTime.MaxDate being the year 10,000 was a shortcut around a problem with TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds.  Which returns a *double*, a value type that has up to 15 significant digits.  Going beyond 10,000 requires more digits.

Which inspires an explanation for the year 9998, there are plenty of icky problems getting close to DateTime.MaxDate.  For example, SQL Server conks out at 3 milliseconds before midnight, .NET at 100 nanoseconds before midnight.  DateTimePicker uses local time which can cause MaxDate to be exceeded in various timezones throughout the day of December 31st.  So the Microsoft programmer did what most any other programmer did before him, he took a shortcut:

```
    public static DateTime MaximumDateTime {
        get {
             DateTime maxSupportedDateTime = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.MaxSupportedDateTime;
             if (maxSupportedDateTime.Year > MaxDateTime.Year)
             {
                 return MaxDateTime;
             }
             return maxSupportedDateTime;
         }
    }
```

This is of course never a real problem, it is not meaningful to handle dates that far into the future.  Use the MaximumDateTime property if you need some kind of validity check in your own code.

Comment: Nice post. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is another non-answer, but maybe it'll be useful to someone. Following the WINAPI route in my comment, `SYSTEMTIME` is limited to dates between 1601 and 30827 because it is based on a FILETIME structure, which stores time as a 64-bit count of 100ns ticks since #1/1/1601#. It further only allows [values less than 0x8000000000000000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which results in the year 30827 upper limit.

The .NET DateTimePicker control is based on the [WINAPI Date and Time Picker control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761726%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so it makes sense that it would have at least these limits. The documentation mentions the switch from the Julian to the Gregorian calendar in 1753, which may explain the `#1/1/1753#` limit coded into the .NET control.

That may help to explain the lower limit, but still doesn't explain the upper limit. Unless someone from the development team chimes in, the only answer to "why?" may be "because it's [hardcoded that way](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/ndp/fx/src/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DateTimePicker.cs#77)".

{Edit: the justification for the [1601 date for SYSTEMTIME](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/03/06/9461176.aspx) appears to be that it was the previous start of a 400-year cycle in the proleptic Gregorian calendar. Still doesn't help explain #12/31/9998#.}

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a proper answer (though I'm still trying to dig). Looking at the source there is a field defined in the `DateTimePicker`:

```
[Browsable(false)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public static readonly DateTime MaxDateTime = new DateTime(9998, 12, 31);
```

In your question you ask why it is "12/31/9998 23:59:59" when in fact it is only "12/31/9998 00:00:00", which is almost more peculiar.

I then searched for usages of this field. It seems to be used only as an absolute bound for the date time picker and nothing else. In fact, the `MaximumDateTime` property looks like this:

```
public static DateTime MaximumDateTime
{
  get
  {
    DateTime supportedDateTime = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.MaxSupportedDateTime;
    if (supportedDateTime.Year > DateTimePicker.MaxDateTime.Year)
      return DateTimePicker.MaxDateTime;
    else
      return supportedDateTime;
  }
}
```

So the maximum date is actually defined by either the current culture's defined maximum supported date, or the absolute maximum supported by the `DateTimePicker`, whichever is less in terms of the year part. For the "en-US" culture the maximum supported date is equal to `DateTime.MaxValue`, so the `MaxDateTime` field is used insteam.

Again, this isn't meant to answer why the particular value is used, but to give more insight on how it is being used within the `DateTimePicker` itself.